# Capybara click on link which executes js doesn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this code while using Capybara:

```
a = page.find(".show-link")
a.click
expect(page).not_to have_css(".someClass.hidden")
```

And I have link

```
<a class="show-link" href="">Show me!</a>
```

I have also js function bind to click event which removes hidden class from element:

```
$("body").on("click", ".show-link",function(){$('.someClass').removeClass('hidden');return false;});
```

But instead of executing my js function on click I get redirected to another page.

I tried to set `href = "#"`, I tried to change `<a>` to `<span>` but doesn't work
script is not executed.

Comment: have you tried adding `:js => true` to your context or test ?

Comment: @fanta tell me, where to add it?!

Answer (score 0):

In your test definition, add `:js => true`, so:

```
describe 'some stuff which requires js', :js => true do
  it 'will test this or that' do
  ...
  end
end
```

Capybara will then use `Selenium` (default driver) to test your javascript functionality. It's quite cool as it uses an actual browser window.

Answer (score 0):

Christian-G is correct if you are using rspec. If in case you are using Minitest the same idea applies but it would be executed something like:

```
test "this is my test" do
  Capybara.current_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver
  #test logic goes here
  Capybara.use_default_driver
end
```

Ideally you would not change the capybara driver inline like this, but put them in your setup and teardown calls for the test. like this:

```
setup do
  Capybara.current_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver
end

teardown do 
  Capybara.use_default_driver
end
```

This is also outlined in the [Capybara documentation](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/4161bbc560631e61e611d59bf797eeb59a6b1021/README.md#using-capybara-with-testunit).

Answer (score 0):

As it was already mentioned, you need to use some driver that supports `js` execution (webkit, poltergeist, selenium).
Also there should be only one matching element, i.e. if there's one element `".someClass.hidden"` and another one `".someClass.shown"` test won't pass

An one more option is that you have wrong usage of Capybara matcher:

`expect(page).not_to have_css(".someClass.hidden")`

should be 

`expect(page).to have_no_css(".someClass.hidden")`

**Why?**

Capybara has logic to wait for something to happen, so in this case it checks that page has `.someClass.hidden` and immediately finds such element. If it were `have_no_css` it will find element, but then retry several times waiting for it to disappear